# Mysql Unknown Punctuation String @ 12 error

Tags: mysql

I cant understand what is wrong with this code. Please help:

```
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER `project`.`insert_project_log` AFTER INSERT ON `project`.`projects`
     FOR EACH ROW insert into 
     project_log(user,title,uploaded_file_name,submitted_at,submitted_by) 
     values(new.user,new.title,new.report_file_name,now(),new.submitted_by)
    //
    DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting:

```
        ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 12
        STR: //
        SQL: 
        DELIMITER //
        CREATE TRIGGER `project`.`insert_project_log` AFTER INSERT ON `project`.`projects`
         FOR EACH ROW insert into 
        project_log(user,title,uploaded_file_name,submitted_at,submitted_by) 
       values(new.user,new.thesis,new.report_file_name,now(),new.submitted_by)
        //
```

Answer (score 1):

Name your trigger in one word or one string encapsulated in backticks

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER insert_project_log AFTER INSERT ON `project`.`projects`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   insert into project_log(user,title,uploaded_file_name,submitted_at,submitted_by) 
   values(new.user,new.title,new.report_file_name,now(),new.submitted_by);
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting errors if i change your code to this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `project`.`insert_project_log` AFTER INSERT ON `project`.`projects`
 FOR EACH ROW insert into 
 project_log(user,title,uploaded_file_name,submitted_at,submitted_by) 
 values(new.user,new.title,new.report_file_name,now(),new.submitted_by)
//DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The change you are pointing out is that you moved DELIMITER;?